# Добавление элементов в массив с уже существующим ключом

Tags: массивы, php

Вот код:

```
$inf['error'] = 'Все не так';
$inf['succes'] = 'Уже так';
$inf['error'] = 'И опять не так';
```

Проблема в том, что error переназначается, а мне нужно добавить новый элемент. Пробовал использовать `.=`, но он дополняет уже существующий элемент, что не годится.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

---

Нужно, чтобы на выходе получилось вот что:

```
$inf = array(
   'error' => 'Все не так',
   'succes' => 'Уже так',
   'error' => 'И опять не так'
);
```

Comment: не бывает двух одинаковых ключей, на то они и ключи. http://ideone.com/2lq5g7

Comment: > Массив - это упорядоченный набор данных. Каждый элемент массива имеет индекс и ключ. Индекс (ключ) служит для однозначной идентификации элемента внутри массива. В одном массиве не может быть двух элементов с одинаковыми индексами. 

(с) эти ваши интернеты.

Comment: Кстати.. Может кто подскажет, правильно ли делаю (делаю по варианту @lampla)? Мне нужно собрать все ошибки, успехи и замечания, так сказать, и выдать их пользователю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$inf['error'][] = 'Все не так';
$inf['succes'][] = 'Уже так';
$inf['error'][] = 'И опять не так';
```

Если я понял мысль :)

Comment: Ну не совсем. Эта штука массивы в массиве создает, как я понял. Я шапку поправил и указал, как должен в итоге выглядеть массив. Проблема в том, что сейчас на выходе error один и тот, который последний ('И опять не так')

Comment: @lampa Если верить комменту выше, то ключи уникальны.. Можно тогда попросить, пожалуйста, получить помощь в разборе массива с помощью foreach? а то у меня не выходит что-то

Comment: @lampa И все-таки вышло) Спасибо!

Comment: @ifernus-w вот [лучшая помощь](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) если у вас возникают сложности с пониманием документации, пожалуйста задайте соответствующий вопрос (с  явным указанием что непонятно, глядишь станет намного проще жить)

Comment: @eitco Всегда смотрю документацию. Тут просто что массив в массиве, следовательно получилось foreach в foreach. Там я слегка затупил, но, включив логику, у меня все получилось =)

Comment: Можно делать двумерный массив:  

    $res=Array();
    $res[]=Array("error", 1);
    $res[]=Array("success", 2);
    $res[]=Array("error", 3);
В таком представлении сохранится хронология появления сообщений.